# SVN Update window in RStudio does not allow to handle conflicts

Tags: svn, rstudio

Since upgrading to the latest version (1.1.383, which included the 'Terminal' pane among other cool stuff) of RStudio (on Windows) I cannot seem to handle conflict situations upon SVN update anymore.

The dialog looks something like below:

```
Updating '.':
Conflict discovered in 
'C:/Users/<UserName>/Documents/RStudioProj/<MyProject>/<MyPackage>/tests/testthat/helper.testers.R'.
Select: (p) postpone, (df) diff-full, (e) edit,
    (mc) mine-conflict, (tc) theirs-conflict,        (s) show all options:
```

In the past, I used to be able to type e.g. 'mc' followed by 'Enter' (cursor placed in the window itself) and continue the update process - now however I cannot figure out how to submit my answer. Is the dialogue window broken?

Or is something just stuck (I also experience some slowness / delay with the latest version of RStudio compared to previous ones)?

Comment: This just seems like it should be a bug report for RStudio. Doesn't really seem appropriate here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug in RStudio 1.1. We'll be releasing a version with a fix in the next few weeks. You can try it now, if you like (let us know if it doesn't resolve your problem!).

https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/

Comment: I have given this a try and it does resolve my issue.